# Get median of group means without breaking piped workflow (or joining back temporary tibble)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

My data have a grouping variable `group`, and I would like to find the median of the group means of `x` so that I can flag groups that have group means of `x` higher than the median group mean of `x`.

This calculation is easy if I save the group means to a tibble `temp`, compare `x_mean` to `median(x_mean)`, and merge back `temp`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2001)

tb <- tibble(group = c(1, 2, rep(3, 3))) %>% 
    mutate(x = runif(n()) + ifelse(group %in% 1:2, 1, 0))
tb
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   group     x
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 1.76 
#> 2     2 1.61 
#> 3     3 0.218
#> 4     3 0.229
#> 5     3 0.153

temp <- tb %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarize(x_mean = mean(x)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(x_hi = (x_mean > median(x_mean)))
temp
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   group x_mean x_hi 
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1     1  1.76  TRUE 
#> 2     2  1.61  FALSE
#> 3     3  0.200 FALSE

tb <- inner_join(tb, temp)
#> Joining, by = "group"
```

Here is the desired output. It may seem odd that 4/5 observations are below the median, but this is possible since my group counts are not equal.

```r
tb
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   group     x x_mean x_hi 
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 1.76   1.76  TRUE 
#> 2     2 1.61   1.61  FALSE
#> 3     3 0.218  0.200 FALSE
#> 4     3 0.229  0.200 FALSE
#> 5     3 0.153  0.200 FALSE
```

I would like to do this without breaking my piped workflow. The following attempt fails because my groups have different counts.

```r
tb <- tb %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(x_mean2 = mean(x)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(x_hi2 = (x_mean > median(x_mean)))
tb
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   group     x x_mean x_hi  x_mean2 x_hi2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>   <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 1.76   1.76  TRUE    1.76  TRUE 
#> 2     2 1.61   1.61  FALSE   1.61  TRUE 
#> 3     3 0.218  0.200 FALSE   0.200 FALSE
#> 4     3 0.229  0.200 FALSE   0.200 FALSE
#> 5     3 0.153  0.200 FALSE   0.200 FALSE
```

Is there a way to grab the median of the group means of `x` without breaking my piped workflow?

<sup>Created on 2019-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `unique`:

```r
library(dplyr)

tb %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(x_mean = mean(x)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(x_hi = x_mean > median(unique(x_mean)))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   group     x x_mean x_hi 
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1     1 1.76   1.76  TRUE 
#> 2     2 1.61   1.61  FALSE
#> 3     3 0.218  0.200 FALSE
#> 4     3 0.229  0.200 FALSE
#> 5     3 0.153  0.200 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

M-M's answer works for the specific case, but I don't think it would be accurate if more than one group had the same mean scores.

```
tb %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(x_mean = mean(x)) %>% 
  ungroup  %>% 
  nest(-x_mean, -group) %>% 
  mutate(x_median = median(x_mean)) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  mutate(x_hi = x_mean > x_median)
```